# Dynamic list element in MvxDialogViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, mvvmcross

We have a dialog inheriting MvxDialogViewController containing two Sections - TheRadios and TheList.

In response to the user changing the radio within TheRadios, we repopulate TheList (in the view model).

How can we bind a Section of a MvxDialogViewController to a dynamic list?

Looking through all the mvvmcross samples I couldn't find an example of this being done. I considered inserting a MvxActionBasedTableViewSource into the relevant Section's TableView but the property is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to bind a list within a Dialog section to a list, then I believe this extension may help you - https://github.com/asednev/MvvmCross.AlexeysExtensions

I'm afraid it is for vNext rather than v3 currently, but I think it should port very easily - I think the only changes needed would be just a few namespace changes (if you do port it, then please send them a pull request with the changes)

Alternatively

- it is open source, so it may give you alternative ideas
- you could consider using a custom or manual binding to INotifyPropertyChanged in order to achieve the table changes you are looking to achieve

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good option, I'll pull his code down tomorrow and take a look